# How can I handle a $_POST variable identifier as a variable?

Tags: php

Re-writing the question here so it's (hopefully) easier to understand.

I have a piece php that received a `$_POST` from a form. Each time a `$_POST` is completed, only one set of data is sent. It could be `$_$POST['boat']` or `$_POST['car']` or `$_POST['dog']` etc. I do not know what the post will contain upon receiving it. If it is `$_POST['dog']` then the value of the post will go into the `$database.dog` table. If it is `$_POST['car']` then the value of the post will head into the `$database.car` table, and so on.

Once a post is made, how can I identify whether the post was called 'car' or 'dog' or 'boat' or anything else ?

Comment: `foreach($_POST as $name => $value)` or `$names = array_keys($_POST)` maybe? Depends on exactly what you are trying to do which you haven't shown.

Comment: This sounds like treating a symptom. What kind of forms are being medicated here?

Comment: or may be `array_intersect(<posted data>,<globals>)`

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but PHP has variable variables. For example `$foo = 'bar'; $bar = 'baz'; echo $$foo;` => `baz`. Notice the second dollar sign `$`

Comment: Probably need to show what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: Typically you would need to know what the data is on the form that is being parsed. Without that info how would you prepare a DB injection once you have the variables defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the key/index and value and print that info if you are unsure what the keys or values will be that are coming from your form POST.

```
function getKeyValuePairs() {
    $stmt = null;
    if(isset($_POST)){    
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $stmt .= $key." => ".$value."<br>";
        } 
    print_r($stmt);
}
```

Because $_POST is global no need to push variable into function.

HTML: run function to print key/value pairs

```
<div>
    <?php echo getKeyValuePairs(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Dale. Actually as it turns out I only needed the `foreach` part to collect both the $key and $value. Much appreciated, and stay safe!

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of ways to do this.  Simply with `if`s:

```
if(isset($_POST['car'])) {
    // do car stuff
}
if(isset($_POST['boat'])) {
    // do boat stuff
}
//etc...
```

Or a `switch`:

```
switch(true) {
    case(isset($_POST['car'])):
        // do car stuff
        break;
    case(isset($_POST['boat'])):
        // do boat stuff
        break;
    //etc...
}
```

To avoid the `if`s or `switch` you can use a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="car">
```

Then use `$_POST['form']` to dynamically build your queries etc...

If `car` or `boat` etc... is the only key under `$_POST` or if it is always the first key then:

```
$form = key($_POST);
```

Comment: Nice to see `switch` making a deserved appearance.

Comment: Yes this is actually what the old system does do. It's just that I am trying to not have to write 160 odd if's/switch parameters for the new system and doing it all by one insert piece of code that find it's own target handling format based on what is being posted, is a little neater I think.

Comment: OK, so if my edit isn't sufficient then you will need to show some code/queries etc... and how you want to use `car`, `boat` etc... and what your POST data looks like now if you don't want to change it.

Comment: Hi AbraCadaver - sorry I have not replied until now. I found Dales answer the easiest and simplest for my question and it works perfectly. I actually only needed a variation of part of his answer so even what he gave was more than needed. Thank you for giving my question options though - they are often what I have used when referring to other peoples questions.

Comment: What was the variation that you're using and what result does it give?